# How to show this outuput?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

My query is

```
SELECT 
    CustBillPayment.CustomerId, CustBillPayment.Customer_Name, 
    CustBillPayment.CustBill_Total, CustBillPayment.CustBill_Paid,
    CustBillPayment.CustBill_ReamingAmt, CustBillPayment.Created_Date, 
    CustBillPayment.Delivery_Date, CustBillPayment.Updated_Date, 
    Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Type, Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Qty, Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Price, 
    Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Total, 
    Pant_Mes.Pant_Type, Pant_Mes.Pant_QTY, Pant_Mes.Pant_Total, 
    Pant_Mes.Pant_Price
FROM 
    ((CustBillPayment 
INNER JOIN
    Shirt_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Shirt_Mes.CustomerId) 
INNER JOIN
    Pant_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Pant_Mes.CustomerId) 
WHERE 
    CustBillPayment.CustomerId = 17
```

Output is like this and shows dublicate rows:

```
CustomerId CustNm  SType   SQty SPrice  STotal PType    PQTY    PTotal  PPrice
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17         lakhan  sType1   2    200     400   PType3   3         900     300
17         lakhan  sType1   2    200     400   PType4   1         400     400
17         lakhan  sType2   1    250     250   PType3   3         900     300
17         lakhan  sType2   1    250     250   PType4   1         400     400
```

but I want

```
CustomerId CustNm  SType   SQty SPrice  STotal PType    PQTY    PTotal  PPrice
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17         lakhan  sType1   2    200     400   PType3   3         900     300
17         lakhan  sType2   1    250     250   PType4   1         400     400
```

Comment: add a select and group by the fields you want: **select [yourfileds] from (your orginal query) group by [yourfields]**

Comment: have you tried to add `Select Distinct` and `Group By` to this query? SType column seems to be good column to group by

Answer (score 1):

You can't `SELECT DISTINCT`, but others may find it helpful. For you is answer under **edit**.

Keyword `DISTINCT` lists unique rows. To learn more about it read this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp.

**EDIT:**

Now I see the problem, I didn't noticed that numbers doesn't fit earlier. Keyword `DISTINCT` won't help in this case. `JOIN` joins `Shirt_Mes` table first, but there are two records, which means it will produce two rows. Next `JOIN` joins table `Pant_Mes` and condition selects two records from this table, too. Each row from earlier is extended for these two records. In this case it produces 2 x 2 rows.

I guess, it's bad table schema. You can do two queries and combine results in application logic:

```
SELECT
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId,
  CustBillPayment.Customer_Name,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Total,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Paid,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_ReamingAmt,
  CustBillPayment.Created_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Delivery_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Updated_Date,
  Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Type,
  Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Qty,
  Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Price,
  Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Total
FROM
  CustBillPayment
  JOIN Shirt_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Shirt_Mes.CustomerId
WHERE
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId=17
```

and

```
SELECT
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId,
  CustBillPayment.Customer_Name,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Total,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Paid,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_ReamingAmt,
  CustBillPayment.Created_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Delivery_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Updated_Date,
  Pant_Mes.Pant_Type,
  Pant_Mes.Pant_QTY,
  Pant_Mes.Pant_Total,
  Pant_Mes.Pant_Price
FROM
  CustBillPayment
  JOIN Pant_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Pant_Mes.CustomerId
WHERE
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId=17
```

Or you can put all goods in one table (I guess it's for e-shop or something similar). Better would be change table schema, but if you have really good reason why to store goods in separate tables (and type of goods isn't good reason) you can do this query:

```
SELECT
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId,
  CustBillPayment.Customer_Name,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Total,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_Paid,
  CustBillPayment.CustBill_ReamingAmt,
  CustBillPayment.Created_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Delivery_Date,
  CustBillPayment.Updated_Date,
  Goods_Mes.Type,
  Goods_Mes.Qty,
  Goods_Mes.Price,
  Goods_Mes.Total
FROM
  CustBillPayment
  JOIN (SELECT Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Type AS Type,
               Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Qty AS Qty,
               Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Price AS Price,
               Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Total AS Total,
               Shirt_Mes.CustomerId FROM Shirt_Mes
        UNION
        SELECT Pant_Mes.Pant_Type AS Type,
               Pant_Mes.Pant_Qty AS Qty,
               Pant_Mes.Pant_Price AS Price,
               Pant_Mes.Pant_Total AS Total,
               Pant_Mes.CustomerId FROM Pant_Mes
        ) Goods_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Goods_Mes.CustomerId
WHERE
  CustBillPayment.CustomerId=17
```

To make the query better, you can remove `Shirt_Total` and `Pant_Total` and substitute `Goods_Mes.Total` with `Goods_Mes.Qty * Goods_Mes.Price`.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustBillPayment.CustomerId,
            CustBillPayment.Customer_Name,
            CustBillPayment.CustBill_Total,
            CustBillPayment.CustBill_Paid,
            CustBillPayment.CustBill_ReamingAmt,
            CustBillPayment.Created_Date,
            CustBillPayment.Delivery_Date,
            CustBillPayment.Updated_Date,
            Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Type,
            Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Qty,
            Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Price,
            Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Total,
            Pant_Mes.Pant_Type,
            Pant_Mes.Pant_QTY,
            Pant_Mes.Pant_Total,
            Pant_Mes.Pant_Price
  FROM ((CustBillPayment INNER JOIN Shirt_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Shirt_Mes.CustomerId) INNER JOIN
        Pant_Mes ON CustBillPayment.CustomerId = Pant_Mes.CustomerId)
 WHERE CustBillPayment.CustomerId = 17
 GROUP BY Shirt_Mes.Shirt_Type
```

Comment: Plz Suggest other query

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT CBP.CustomerId, CBP.Customer_Name, 
       CBP.CustBill_Total, CBP.CustBill_Paid, 
       CBP.CustBill_ReamingAmt, CBP.Created_Date, 
       CBP.Delivery_Date, CBP.Updated_Date, 
       SMES.Shirt_Type, SMES.Shirt_Qty, SMES.Shirt_Price, 
       SMES.Shirt_Total, PMES.Pant_Type, PMES.Pant_QTY,    
       PMES.Pant_Total, PMES.Pant_Price 
FROM   CustBillPayment AS CBP 
LEFT JOIN Shirt_Mes AS SMES ON CBP.CustomerId = SMES.CustomerId 
LEFT JOIN Pant_Mes AS PMES ON CBP.CustomerId = PMES.CustomerId 
WHERE CBP.CustomerId = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct and group by will only work if the records are unique.

Distinct will still bring back all 4 rows due to pant_type being different in each row. The same goes for the group by.

What is the final output you are expecting as the required output at the top does not make sense with regards to pant_type?

Comment: CustomerId CustNm  SType   SQty SPrice  STotal PType    PQTY    PTotal  PPrice
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17         lakhan  sType1   2    200     400   PType3   3         900     300
17         lakhan  sType2   1    250     250   PType4   1         400     400